# How to Show Subset Sum $\le_p$ 3-Partition

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, np-complete, np

Given a set of integers S (positive and negative, may contain duplicates) can S be divided into three disjoint subsets that all sum to the same value? Prove this problem is NP-complete.

---

Is it possible to show directly that Subset Sum $\le_p$ 3-Partition, or would I have to do

Subset Sum $\le_p$ Partition $\le_p$ 3-Partition?